# WriteStream to csv is not working getting error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("app2").getOrCreate()

val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")
  .option("subscribe", args(0))
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()
val checkPoint = "outputKafka/checkpoint/"

val newDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

val df2 = newDf.withColumn("Primary_Type",split(col("value"),",")(5))
               .withColumn("Create_Date",split(col("value"),",")(2))

val pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"

val finalDf = df2.withColumn("DateNew", unix_timestamp(df2("Create_Date"), pattern)
                 .cast("timestamp"))

finalDf.withWatermark("DateNew","500 milliseconds")
  .groupBy(window(finalDf("DateNew"),"2 minutes"),col("Primary_Type"))
  .agg(count("*").as("Crime_Count"))
  .select("window.start","window.end","Primary_Type","Crime_Count")
  .writeStream.format("csv")
  .option("format", "append")
  .option("path",args(1)+"kafka.csv")
  .option("checkpointLocation",checkPoint)
  .option("header", "true")
  .outputMode("append")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(20.seconds)).start().awaitTermination()
```

Getting Below Error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations
>   on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
>
> at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$UnsupportedOperationChecker$$throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:374)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.checkForStreaming(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:110)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:235)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:299)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:296)
>           at com.mindtree.chicago.Question2$.main(Question2.scala:74)
>           at com.mindtree.chicago.Question2.main(Question2.scala)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: Try replacing `finalDf("DateNew")` with just `col("DateNew")`. Maybe it's referencing `finalDf` which is not watermarked.

Comment: okay thanks for you suggestion, will this @vinsce